# File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets on rails 5.2.0

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have following problem.
"File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets."

Following gems I have installed
gem 'bootstrap'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'

File: Application name change from css to scss.
In the application.scss file I add the lines

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

I bundle install and afterwards restart the server. 
But still the same error message. It will be great if somebody had the same issue and found a solution, all written solutions on stackoverflow doesn't work.

Comment: Did you remove all of the default require statements in application.scss? It should be blank other than your 2 @import statements.

Comment: Yes, all dafault statement I delete before.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I worked on topic and the working solution:

- add `'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.3'` to Gemfile and save
- `gem install sprockets-rails` in command line of project. Version at least 2.3.2, now 3.2.1 is available
- `bundle install` in command line of project
- rename file `application.css` to `application.scss` under `/app/assets/stylesheets`
- The only line for bootstrap is `@import "bootstrap";` at file application.scss
- start rails again by `rails s` in command line of project
- go to home page with some code for bootstrap 4.1.3 inside.

You can check my code free https://bitbucket.org/ArtLion74/myrecepies commit with name Bootstrap working in chrome and firefox.

Regards, Artur

_______________________ old answer ____________________

it's not RoR problem. You didn't say that you see error in ... Chrome :) I had the same. Check in Firefox and ... surprise - working. Problem is only on Chrome. Strange is that after switching to Chrome - it's start working - without errors but without bootstrap formatting too :( I really don't get it :(

Problem is on www client side Chrome - not in RoR.

Comment: Isn't this a terrible solution for Rails 6 because you aren't leveraging webpacker? The whole point is to avoid using gem wrappers for js libraries.

Comment: The above answer was written a year before Rails 6 was released, and the OP said they are using Rails 5.2.0 @ArthurCollé.